# Can the spell Sunbeam harm the same creature multiple times?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw, blind

[*Sunbeam*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sunbeam)'s text reads:

> A beam of brilliant light flashes out from your hand in a 5-foot-wide, 60-foot-long line. Each creature in the line must make a Constitution saving throw. On a failed save, a creature takes 6d8 radiant damage and is blinded until your next turn. On a successful save, it takes half as much damage and isn't blinded by this spell. [...]
>
> You can create a new line of radiance as your action on any turn until the spell ends.

Is my understanding of how this spell works correct?

My interpretation: A creature may be affected by beams over and over. If a creature makes its saving throw, it can no longer be *blinded* by additional beams. However, on subsequent turns, it still needs to make a Con save against the damage. Is that correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Any failed saving throw results in damage *and* blinding

Each time a creature is targeted with a beam of light from the spell, it must roll the saving throw, and it suffers the effects as normal. Passing any one saving throw does not confer any protection from the effects of failing future saving throws against the same spell. The spell's text specifies that on a successful save, a creature *isn't* blinded by the spell. This is written in the present tense: it just means that the creature doesn't get blinded *right now*. There's nothing that says it can't be blinded by future light beams from the same spell.

Generally, if saving against a spell once confers any kind of ongoing protection against that spell, this will be clearly spelled out in the spell's text. For example, the [*Eyebite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/eyebite) spell says (emphasis added):

> On each of your turns until the spell ends, you can use your action to target another creature but **can't target a creature again if it has succeeded on a saving throw against this casting of *eyebite*.**

*Sunbeam* does not contain any text like this.

Comment: While I understand your reasoning based on the fact that _Eyebite_ explicitly specifies that a successful saving throw gives immunity to any further instance of the same spell, I'm still not convinced. The description of _Sunbeam_ says that a creature which succeeds in the saving throw isn't blinded _by this **spell**_, not _by this [single] beam_.

Comment: @StackLloyd Given that it doesn't specify "this casting" like *Eyebite* does, are you arguing that succeeding on a saving throw against *Sunbeam* should grant permanent immunity to blindness from all castings of *Sunbeam* by all casters?

Comment: I have a squirt gun, which I can use 4 times before running out of water. I squirt it at you, and you shift to avoid the spray. (Reflex save!)
You are not wetted by this squirt gun. Is there any reason to believe that you will not be wetted if you are hit by the next squirt?

Answer (score -1):

### You are correct.

The spell description says that a creature that makes its save "isn't blinded **by this spell**." It doesn't say "isn't blinded on this turn." This means that it cannot be blinded on future turns during the duration of this casting of *sunbeam*.

However, there is no verbiage that states that a creature that has made its save can't take any more damage from this spell. Therefore, if such a creature subsequently finds itself in the path of new sunbeam during the duration of same casting, it will still be harmed by the spell, and will need to make another Constitution saving throw for half damage. If it fails the save, it will take full damage, but not be blinded.

Comment: This is especially nice as Divine Sorcerer who can quicken the original casting and then apply the damage twice in the first round.

Comment: I'm not convinced that passing the first saving throw makes a creature immune to future blinding attempts from the same spell. It just says the creature *isn't* blinded, in the present tense. It doesn't say it can't be blinded by the spell in the future, it just isn't blinded *now*. Usually if a successful save grants ongoing protection against future effects of the same spell, this is explicitly spelled out (e.g. see *Eyebite*).

Comment: @RyanThompson Rather than focusing on the tense of the verb (as present tense is also the tense of general truth, absoluteness, giving what I'm about to explain even more significance), I'd focus on the "by this _spell_" part. It's a clear distinction from the _beam_ (s) you can subsequently cast as an action after the first instance of the spell. A creature can't be (_isn't_) blinded by the "whole" _**spell**_, not by that single _beam_.

Comment: @StackLloyd It isn't blinded by the spell *at that moment* but doesn't say it can't be blinded by the spell later. It says "you can create a new line of radiance" which presumably has the same effect as the ones before it, which is 6d8 radiant damage and being blinded on a failed save, or half damage and no blinding if the save is successful.

Comment: @JohnClifford Since the text distinguishes between the _spell_ itself and an eventual subsequent _beam_ and the saving throw part cites the first instead of the latter, without any temporal reference (there's no _at that moment_, or _in this turn_, etc.), as a DM, I'd rule that the _Sunbeam_ **spell** can't blind that creature after it succeeds on the saving throw, while it can still deal damage with ulterior _beams_.

Comment: @StackLloyd I can see where you're coming from but logically that doesn't make sense: why should any given beam of light be more or less likely to blind something on the basis of whether it was blinded or not by a *different* one? It isn't any less radiant lighty. :P

Comment: @JohnClifford They're not different, they come from the same spell, so every blast of that spell is the same. Thus, how's _that_ logical? If the **same** light as before wasn't enough to blind me, why should it be able to blind me anytime afterwards?

Comment: The saving throw is against the beam; passing it is analogous to resisting its full impact. Resisting being blinded by one beam doesn't make the next beam duller.

Comment: @StackLloyd I guarantee you that the longer you look straight at the sun, the more likely you are to be blinded, even though the sun isn't getting any brighter while you look at it. (I don't recommend testing this empirically.)

Comment: @RyanThompson While a real-life example like that can't be put against in-game logic (I mean, I can't gain control of a storm and call lightnings from it as I please, however much I chant a spell...), since characters have superhuman capabilities, what makes me actually reconsider my opinion is the reply you gave to my comment under your answer. You're right, my literal interpretation leads to an illogical exageration. Yours is more reasonable.

Comment: @RyanThompson While a real-life example like that can't be put against in-game logic (I mean, I can't gain control of a storm and call lightnings from it as I please, however much I chant a spell...), since characters have superhuman capabilities, what makes me actually reconsider my opinion is the reply you gave to my comment under your answer. You're right, my literal interpretation leads to an illogical exageration. Yours is more reasonable.